# How could I concatenate a variable as part of the string (for a filename)?

Tags: string, matlab

In python, I have scripted as follows:

```
File_name = 'Image1' + str(index) + '_merge_E.nii.gz'
```

How could do the same in MATLAB?

Here, `index = 1:99`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a string is nothing more than an array of chars, you can easily perform an array concatenation:

```
string1='hello';
string2='world';
string3='!';

myString=[string1 ' ' string2 ' ' string3];
```

This will create the string `"hello world !"` (mind the spaces!).
The conversion between number and char is pretty straightforward in Matlab as well: you might want to check `num2str()`. In your case you'll have:

```
string1='Image1';
string2=num2str(index);
string3='_merge_E.nii.gz';
```

or the one-line solution:

```
Filename=['Image1' num2str(index) '_merge_E.nii.gz'];
```

Comment: @JesuKiranSpurgen If this answers your question, you should consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. This is better than thanks as it gives the person who helped you some reputation points. It also lets everybody else see that the problem has been resolved.